# WCF Insert data into My SQL

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am trying to insert data from window phone into sql server through WCF.
I had follow this example to edit my project..[insert data](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e788c532-17e1-4255-b228-61bf261d5c4f)
but the data does not insert into my database. 
My coding is as below:

Is put under WindowPhone MainPage.xaml.cs.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Insert textbox1.text into database
            string empId = textBox1.Text;
            Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();
            proxy.AddEmployeeCompleted += new EventHandler<AddEmployeeCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_AddEmployeeCompleted);
            proxy.AddEmployeeAsync(empId);
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }


private void proxy_AddEmployeeCompleted(object sender, AddEmployeeCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool bb = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Result);
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        if (bb == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Added Successfully !!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Insert record,Try Again !!");
        }
    }
```

the code at Service1.svc.cs

```
namespace MyService
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public bool AddEmployee(string empId)
        {
            try
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext cont = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                MyEmployee data = new MyEmployee();
                data.EmpId = empId;
                cont.MyEmployees.InsertOnSubmit(data);
                cont.SubmitChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and the code at IService1.cs

```
namespace MyService
{

    [ServiceContract]

    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]

        bool AddEmployee(string empId);
    }
}
```

Any wrong with my coding?

Comment: Did you check if your code on the server-side is ever reached?

Comment: How to check it? i follow this link to do the insert data. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e788c532-17e1-4255-b228-61bf261d5c4f but i dont understand the solution.

Comment: I assume you own the code of the service definition on the server-side. Set a breakpoint on the entry point of your service definition code and see if it breaks and what happens next (exception or whatever).

Comment: It show me requested registry access is not allowed.What does it means?

Comment: How can I know? I think you should show us the whole code that is involved in this transaction as well as the type/message/stacktrace of the exception if any.

Comment: I had edit my code..please hv a look.

Comment: and DataClasses1DataContext is exactly WHAT?

Comment: that is the Linq to SQL classes which i use drag my sql table into it.

Comment: So? What line is failing? What's the exception you're getting, the stack trace, the message? Any inner exception?

Comment: Hi, i had find solution already, Is because of my database table. I make my all of my 3 entity must not be null. but in my coding  i just try to insert 1 data only. ..Thank you.